# Chrome Most Visited Tumbnails display blank image

Tags: google-chrome

Im having the exact same issue as this:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=475108
It should be fixed since ~ 1 month, but im still having the problem on Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m, using Windows 8.1 64 bit.

I tried everything i found in the web, like deleting a thumbnail - restore it - reboot. Or what is described here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/34690/refresh-most-visited-page-icons-in-google-chrome/

Now after messing around the whole day, im kinda giving up and ask you guys for help please. The error in the console looks like "GET chrome-search://thumb/*XYZ*::ERR_FAILED Failed to load resource"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly Google's final fix, will only work after a fresh install (wipe) of the latest Chrome. So "fixed" in this case means > 
After a clean install the problem never appears again. But if you are "only" updating Chrome from the buggy to the new version, the problem still exists.

---

Now u got 2 options:

EITHER keep your current Chrome and all private data, but install an addon like "Speed Dial [FVD]", which has same (plus more) features as the default new-tab-page. In there, things like most-visited/recently-closed will work now! (including picture thumbnails)

OR you deinstall/wipe chrome and do a complete fresh install with default settings. Obviously all your private data is gone by chosing this option. You could take backups of your personal data first, but there is a high chance, the initial problem returns too, if you re-import old settings/content into the fresh Chrome.

Comment: you could also try to use googles account-sync feature and see if you can get your private data from the buggy version into the fresh one, with this method. im not using google sync, so i cant tell you. but if somebody tried it, let me know if the original problem returns or not.